What exactly does it mean for two bosons to be in the same state?
If I understand QM correctly, it's a fact that two bosons can have the same wave function in principle. What I'm wondering is if the particles governed by the wave functions can also be in the same place at the same time etc. Is it correct to conclude from the fact that collecting a bunch of bosons together doesn't cause all of their wavefunctions to broaden due to exclusion, that there must be a possibility for multiple particles (not just probability waves) to be in exactly the same place? Or is it unknown, since many point-like particles could occupy the same general region, having the same distributions, without themselves being in the same place?

The only thing I want to add to both correct answers is that when we say "particle" in quantum mechanics, what we really mean is "quantum of energy". When we mean "in the same place" it means "energy detectable by a detector system in the same volume element". In case of photons we can detect as many of them as we want in the same detector volume at the same time. In case of electrons we could only detect two with the exact same energy and momentum (spin would be opposite) at the same time. This is really just a statement about simultaneously detectable combinations of E, p, L and q.


What exactly does it mean for two bosons to be in the same state?

"In the same state" usually implies: (1) that the full quantum mechanical two-body problem has been reduced down to an effective single-particle problem, the single-particle states of which I will denote as
$$
\left\{\phi_i(\mathbf{x})
\right\}\;;
$$
and (2) that the two bosons both are described using the same "orbital," a la
$$
\Psi(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2) = \phi_n(\mathbf{x}_1)\phi_n(\mathbf{x}_2)\;.\tag{A}
$$
This is possible because the full bosonic wave function has to be symmetric on interchange of $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$.
This can be contrasted with a fermionic wave function, which has to be antisymmetric and so a state like Eq. (A) is not possible for fermions.


...a possibility for multiple particles (not just probability waves) to be in exactly the same place?

The use of the word "be" is strictly improper. The wavefunction doesn't tell you "where" a particle "is." The wavefunction tells you the probability density that, if you measure, you would find one particle at $\mathbf{x}_1$ and one particle at $\mathbf{x}_2$.
The probability density to measure both particles at $\mathbf{x}$ is, from Eq. (A):
$$
|\Psi(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x})|^2 = |\phi_n(\mathbf{x})|^2|\phi_n(\mathbf{x})|^2
$$

So is it correct to say that, due to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle and the limits of experimentation, if we take a particle-wave duality interpretation like pilot wave or many worlds, we can't know if it is possible for two particles to be in exactly the same place at the same time, but the most we can do is localize them to being in the same given region? Would it be correct under another interpretation to say that the wave is all that exists and that therefore both particles being in the same "location" is equivalent to saying they have the same wave function?

According to the theory it is possible for two bosons to "be at the same place at the same time." The probability that both are within $\delta^3 x$ of $\vec x$ is $P=\int_{\delta^3 x} d^3x |\Psi(\vec x,\vec x)|^2$. The language caveats in my answer are just related to the usual meaning of the wave function. I.e., that to observe the wave pattern requires multiple measurements on identically prepared systems.

Being within a delta of a position vector means being in a volumetric region, no? That doesn't seem to be the same as saying that two particles share the same point coordinates exactly, again assuming an interpretation where underlying particles have a definite location. Am I missing something?

In order to convert from a probability density to a probability, one must integrate over a volume. You can make the test volume $\delta^3 x$ as small as you would like.

I guess my point is that, as small as the volume is, it's still a volume, so isn't there a necessary element of imprecision?

I guess I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I think not really. Whatever imprecision you think there might be with converting a probability density to a probability, it can always be made negligibly small compared to the precision of your physical measuring apparatus.

The question implies an overly classical interpretation of the wave function, that is a follows:
A particle in a pure state $\psi(x)$ is a point particle randomly distributed with probability distribution:
$$ P(x) = |\psi(x)|^2 $$
This is not correct. What is correct is that the particle is described by a wave function $\psi(x)$, and that has no classical description.
Applying that interpretation to 2 particles: A two particle system with wave function $\psi(x_1, x_2)$, would have a probability that both particles are at the same position given by:
$$  P(x) = |\psi(x, x)|^2 $$
But neither particle has a position, they jointly have an entangled wave function.
Now if we're talking identical bosons, then:
$$ \psi(x_1, x_2) = +\psi(x_2, x_1) $$
If they states can be factor into single particle eigenstates, $\phi_n(x_i)$ then we can write a symmetric state as:
$$ \psi_{nn}(x_1, x_2) \propto \big(
\phi_n(x_1)\phi_n(x_2) + 
\phi_n(x_2)\phi_n(x_1)
\big)
$$
Here, the two particles are in the same quantum state (labeled by quantum number(s) $n$).
The amplitude at for particle 1 and 2 to have the same coordinate, $x$, is:
$$ \psi_{nn}(x, x) = 
\phi_n(x)\phi_n(x) 
$$
tl;dr The idea that the above state is a statistical description of two randomly distributed point particles that can occupy the same point position is too classical to be useful. Just go with the wave function.

Since you are calling $P$ a probability distribution, not a number distribution, your normalization is wrong. It is only correct that $|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|ab\rangle + |ba\rangle)$ when $a\neq b$. When $a=b$ the cross terms contribute so the correct normalization is 1/2 not $1/\sqrt{2}$

Would this depend on the interpretation of quantum mechanics? For example, under the Copenhagen interpretation, is it correct to say that bosons are just waves and that for two bosons to be in the same state implies that there is nothing different between them? And under pilot wave or many worlds, does it imply that there is something different in terms of the particle, but that we can't see it because we only see the wave?

@hft are you talking about the eq for $\psi_{nn}(x, x)$? If so, that is why I said "amplitude", not probabilioty.

@FranciscoSkrobola maybe. I don't care about many worlds or hidden variables. I'm talking about quantum mechanics, where the wave function is just this thing we use to do calculations. I think a lot of the problems with this whole question is the desire to give it too much meaning, which I am avoiding,  QM is an approximation to the reality (QFT), where everything in a field and there are no particles (unless there are), The need to understand the wave function by saying a particle (eq electron on hydrogen) has a randomly distributed point (which is too classical), leads to misunderstanding.

I'm saying you should write $\psi_{nn} = \phi_n\phi_n$ not $\psi_{nn}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\phi_n\phi_n$

@hft that does look better, but why doesn't plugging in $x_1=x_2=x$ and performing basic manipulation lead me astray?

@JEB because what you wrote is only the right normalization when the single particle states are orthogonal. You are probably thinking about Fermions and the Slater determinant formulation. In general, if you want to try to write something down for both bosons and fermions, the normalization factor is kind of awkward and not just $1/\sqrt{N!}$ like it is for a Slater determinant.

@hft thanks. that is exactly what went wrong. My normalization is proven experimentally wrong by the existence of lasers.
